# Digits in std::string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, for-loop, while-loop

Can you please help me find digits in string without using functions like isdigit? I can only use for loop and pointers. If I have

```
std::string s {"A year has 365 days"}
```

Why can't I do something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
    while (s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9) v[i].push_back(s[i]);
}
```

I know this would store digits 3 6 and 5 in vector and not number 365. But I don't understand why my while loop doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work because your looping condition is __"it's a digit"__, so while it's a digit add it to `v[i]`. And what if the string doesn't start with a digit?

Comment: But if it's not a digit it won't do anything? I don't understand because it won't work even if I use. 
`if (s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9) {
while (s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9) v[i].push_back(s[i]); 
i++;
}`,

Comment: what do you think happens to `i` on the line `while (s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9) v[i].push_back(s[i]);`?

Comment: this code is going to loop forever, you dont increment i in your while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I'm understanding you correctly, you want to store just the digits?  If so then maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
 string s = "A year has 365 days";
 vector<string> storedNums = {};

 for(int i = 0; i < (s.length() - 1); i++) {
    if (s[i] >= 48 && s[i] <= 57) {
        storedNums.push_back(s[i]);
    }
}
```

Here I'm using the ascii values between 48 and 57 (digit chars) to decipher if the current character is a digit. Using the while loop will put you in an infinite loop if the condition is true.  This means once your iteration reached '3', it will continue to sit in the while loop.  So your vector will keep calling push_back forever because the current condition is met and does not have a base case to break out of the while loop.

**Edit:**
This code has two mistakes that I did not initially catch.  First, the vector should be a `vector<char>` and not a `vector<string>`. Second, it has come to my attention that the condition should not be `i < s.length()-1` and it should be `i < s.length()`. The way I initially typed skips the last index in the loop and it works with the given string, however if *"days"* is taken out of the string, it will only print `36`.  The following code has been adjusted for readability and has been compiled to make sure it works:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "A year is 365";
    vector<char> nums;
    int length = s.length();

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9') {
            nums.push_back(s[i]);
            cout << s[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your loop end condition should be `i < s.length()`. Your current code will skip the last character or do something even worse if the string is empty.

Comment: Even if restricting to ASCII may be fine, consider using `'0'` and `'9'` to increase readabiltiy of the code.

Comment: @Bob__ yes I totally agree with you

Answer (score 2):

You're looping over a sequence and conditionally copying elements to another container. The standard library has a [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) algorithm specifically for this task.

```
std::string s{ "A year has 365 days" };
std::vector<char> v;

std::copy_if(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(v), ::isdigit);
```

If you insist on not using `isdigit` you can provide your own predicate (a lambda in this example).

```
std::copy_if(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(v),
    [](char ch) { return '0' <= ch && ch <= '9'; }
);
```

Comment: I agree, but that *"I can only use for loop and pointers"* in OP question really clashes with that C++11 tag...

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't I do something like this:
>
> ```
> for (int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
>     while (s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9') v[i].push_back(s[i]);
> }
> ```

That won't work because the program will execute the `while` statement for ever if the conditional were `true`. You need to use `if` fnstead of `while`.

```
for (int i=0; i<s.size(); i++)
{
   if (s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9')
   {
      v[i].push_back(s[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string str {"A year has 365 days"};   
std::vector<char> vec;   
for(const char c: str)   
{
  if (c>='0' && c<='9')
  {
    vec.push_back(c);
  }   
}
```

Comment: Do you mind elaborate? Even if the code posted may answer the question, an explanation could be beneficial to others and increase its value.

Comment: First, we create a string object will be used as a test, then a vector where all digits will be stored.  Then the for loop iterates over the string.  Each character in the string is checked to see if it is a digit or not.  If it is then it is added to the vector.